# What to do to get website's link on clicking button in android app

Tags: android

I am making an android application as a beginner.
What can be done to do the following.

When I click a button in my app, then it should display some website's link.

Comment: If you can reword/edit your question to ask something more specific then it will be easier for others to offer help and answers. Right now this is too vague. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Welcoem to Stack Overflow.  I have fixed a fe English issues with your post.  And I have also reworded it.  Please check to see if this is what you intended.

Answer (score 0):

try to use this function:

```
public static void openWebBrowser(Activity activity, String url) {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        try {
            activity.startActivity(intent);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
            Log.w("error:", "no webBrowser detected");
        }
    }
```